# Firebase: Transaction read and update multiple documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With this code I can read and update single document in the transaction.

```
// Update likes in post
var docRef = admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("posts")
  .doc(doc_id);

let post = await admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => t.get(docRef));
if (!post.exists) {
  console.log("post not exist")
}
postData = { ...post.data(), id: post.id };
let likes = postData.likes || 0;
var newLikes = likes + 1;
await post.ref.update({ likes: newLikes });
```

**Question:**
But I need to read and update **multiple** documents and each one update depending on their content. For example I want to update number of likes in posts collection as in my code but also update number of total likes in my profile document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update multiple documents in a transaction, you call `t.update()` multiple times.

```
let promise = await admin.firestore().runTransaction(transaction => {
  var post = transaction.get(docRef);
  var anotherPost = transaction.get(anotherDocRef);

  if (post.exists && anotherPost.exists) {
    var newLikes = (post.data().likes || 0) + 1;
    await transaction.update(docRef, { likes: newLikes });
    newLikes = (anotherPost.data().likes || 0) + 1;
    await transaction.update(anotherdocRef, { likes: newLikes });
  }
})
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: But here we read data only from ONE document. I need to update anotherdocRef depending on their likes number and not on docRef likes number.

Comment: You can call `transaction.get(...)` on multiple document reference in the transaction.

Comment: I copied that from your code. Updated now to remove the likely cause of that problem. But note that I'm trying to show that you can call `transaction.get(...)` multiple from within your transaction handler to solve your problem.

Comment: Found error: need to add async before "transaction =>" and put await on post and anotherPost declaration

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do firestore transaction updates all fail or succeed like batch updates?