# Firestore transaction update multiple document

Tags: firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update documents in one collection.

```
my_collection
     document_1
        field_1
        field_2
     document_2
        field_1
        field_2
```

My code:

```
exports.aggregateUsers = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onWrite(function(change, 
context) {
const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
const oldDocument = change.before.data() || null;

return firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    var oldInstanceRef;
    var instanceRef;

    var oldInstanceDoc;
    var instanceDoc;
    if (document != null) {
        instanceRef = firestore.collection("counters").doc("instance_counter").collection("instances").doc(document.instance);
        instanceDoc = transaction.get(instanceRef);

        var newNumberOfUsers = (instanceDoc.data().number_of_users || 0) + 1;
        transaction.set(instanceRef, { number_of_users: newNumberOfUsers });
    } 
    if (oldDocument != null) {
        oldInstanceRef = firestore.collection("counters").doc("instance_counter").collection("instances").doc(oldDocument.instance);
        oldInstanceDoc = transaction.get(oldInstanceRef);

        var newPrevNumberOfUsers = (oldInstanceDoc.data().number_of_users || 0) + 1;
        transaction.set(instanceRef, { number_of_users: newPrevNumberOfUsers });
    }


}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("invalid-argument", error.code, error.message);
});
});
```

Errors:

```
instanceDoc.data is not a function
```

I am using transcation in cloud function to aggregate number of users, not using distributed counter, because of low traffic app. My question is how to update field's value in each document? Thank you

Comment: Have you read the documentation about transactions?  Please edit the question with the code you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: Yes, I did, my reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088261/10086063

Comment: It's not clear from your code exactly how instanceDoc gets defined.  The origin is hidden behind `change.after`, which we don't see here.  It also seems like you might be working within Cloud Functions, which is a really important detail to talk about.  Without seeing the entire, minimal function, and how exactly you are invoking it, it's impossible to see what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: edited my entire function

Comment: And what are you doing to invoke your function?  Please edit the question and be very specific about what you're doing and what you expect to happen in response.

Comment: solved by using transaction.getAll, thanks for your support

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot the async/await.

Try this:

1. `async` before `transaction` parameter
2. `await` before `transaction.get(<some_ref_here>)`

```js
return firestore.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    var oldInstanceRef;
    var instanceRef;

    var oldInstanceDoc;
    var instanceDoc;
    if (document != null) {
        instanceRef = firestore.collection("counters").doc("instance_counter").collection("instances").doc(document.instance);
        instanceDoc = await transaction.get(instanceRef);

        var newNumberOfUsers = (instanceDoc.data().number_of_users || 0) + 1;
        transaction.set(instanceRef, { number_of_users: newNumberOfUsers });
    } 
    if (oldDocument != null) {
        oldInstanceRef = firestore.collection("counters").doc("instance_counter").collection("instances").doc(oldDocument.instance);
        oldInstanceDoc = await transaction.get(oldInstanceRef);

        var newPrevNumberOfUsers = (oldInstanceDoc.data().number_of_users || 0) + 1;
        transaction.set(instanceRef, { number_of_users: newPrevNumberOfUsers });
    }


}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("invalid-argument", error.code, error.message);
});
```