# Firestore: Running transaction on top 3 users in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an app that constantly takes top N users and edits/moves them to a different "queue" for processing.

I am trying to do this with a transaction so I don't end up same document being processed twice by concurrent edits since there are parallel scanners.

I am not sure how to achieve this using a transaction since from my naive understanding the transaction seems to run on a docRef.

So far I have code similar to below following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087616/firebase-transaction-read-and-update-multiple-documents) but I think this will only work for first item and not the second? In other words, if the doc is updated by another processor user, it will rerun but won't do anything i.e. pick the next 2 top users that are still not processed? Is there a way I can achieve this? I realize I may need some kind of loop here?

Is it possible the second doc update will be atomic i.e. after the first doc update another concurrent user will pick up the second doc as the top item?

```
var entriesRef = db.collection('entries');
var snapshot = entriesRef.where("status", "=", 'PENDING').orderBy("createTime").limit(2);
var docRefs = [];
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  docRefs.push(entriesRef.doc(doc.id));
});

let promise = await admin.firestore().runTransaction(transaction => {
  var post = transaction.get(docRefs[0]);
  var anotherPost = transaction.get(docRefs[1]);

  if (post.status === 'PENDING' && anotherPost.status === 'PENDING') {
    var newStatus = 'BEING PROCESSED'
    await transaction.update(docRef[0], { status: newStatus });
    await transaction.update(docRef[1], { status: newStatus });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible the second doc update will be atomic i.e. after the first doc update another concurrent user will pick up the second doc as the top item?

All documents that you `get()` and `update()` using a transaction object will be processed atomically.  That's the whole point of the transaction.  If any of the documents you `get()` is modified by some other client during the transaction, the transaction handler function will be retried.  You code needs to be prepared for this.

In your specific case, if one of the documents that you transact with changes status and becomes ineligible for whatever you want to do, you might want to consider retrying the whole thing with two new documents that you get from a new query outside of the transaction.  Also you might want to consider what to do if you don't get enough valid documents to work with before entering the transaction.